# Play deploy on Heroku failed uncaught fatal error from Akka actorsystem

Tags: java, scala, playframework, jvm, akka

I am trying to deploy my Play/Scala 2.5.4 to Heroku (with free dyno). I am getting this error and application is not going live.

```
20:51:27 web.1   |  2017-08-12 20:51:27,035 [error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem [application]
```

JVM options:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Increasing memory doesn't help. Any idea why I am getting this error ? App runs fine on Mac.

Comment: that's the entire error message you get? No stackrace?

Comment: Increase verbosity and try to redeploy so you get more info about the issue?

Comment: Are you using akka typed?

Comment: Works fine after addressing a runtime/class path related issue. Still can't understand why it impacted Akka - sorry for not including complete logs - at the moment I dont have it